# Compare decimals in python

Tags: python, testing, decimal

I want to be able to compare Decimals in Python. For the sake of making calculations with money, clever people told me to use Decimals instead of floats, so I did. However, if I want to verify that a calculation produces the expected result, how would I go about it?

```
>>> a = Decimal(1./3.)
>>> a
Decimal('0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125')
>>> b = Decimal(2./3.)
>>> b
Decimal('0.66666666666666662965923251249478198587894439697265625')
>>> a == b
False
>>> a == b - a
False
>>> a == b - Decimal(1./3.)
False
```

so in this example a = 1/3 and b = 2/3, so obviously b-a = 1/3 = a, however, that cannot be done with Decimals.

I guess a way to do it is to say that I expect the result to be 1/3, and in python i write this as

```
Decimal(1./3.).quantize(...)
```

and then I can compare it like this:

```
(b-a).quantize(...) == Decimal(1./3.).quantize(...)
```

So, my question is: Is there a cleaner way of doing this? How would you write tests for Decimals?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are not using `Decimal` the right way.

```
>>> from decimal import *

>>> Decimal(1./3.)                  # Your code
Decimal('0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125')

>>> Decimal("1")/Decimal("3")       # My code
Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333')
```

In "your code", you actually perform "classic" floating point division -- then convert the result to a decimal. The error introduced by *floats* is propagated to your *Decimal*.

In "my code", I do the *Decimal* division. Producing a correct (but truncated) result up to the last digit.

---

Concerning the rounding. If you work with monetary data, you must know the rules to be used for rounding in your business. If not so, using `Decimal` will *not* automagically solve all your problems. Here is an example: $100 to be share between 3 shareholders.

```
>>> TWOPLACES = Decimal(10) ** -2

>>> dividende = Decimal("100.00")
>>> john = (dividende / Decimal("3")).quantize(TWOPLACES)
>>> john
Decimal('33.33')
>>> paul = (dividende / Decimal("3")).quantize(TWOPLACES)
>>> georges = (dividende / Decimal("3")).quantize(TWOPLACES)
>>> john+paul+georges
Decimal('99.99')
```

Oups: missing $.01 (free gift for the bank ?)

Comment: That makes sense. But it is still necessary to truncate/quantize the result in order to make proper comparisons?

Comment: @Eldamir I have updated the answer with some elements relevant to the comparison. For monetary value, you will truncate/round all your result to a fixed number of decimal after the "dot". Usually 2 -- but something 4 ou 5. Anyway, you should have some clear rules for that, otherwise you will end up with cents "floating around" -- just like in "Superman 3" :D

Answer (score 3):

Your verbiage states you want to to monetary calculations, minding your round off error.  Decimals are a good choice, as they yield EXACT results under addition, subtraction, and multiplication with other Decimals.

Oddly, your example shows working with the fraction "1/3".  I've never deposited exactly "one-third of a dollar" in my bank... it isn't possible, as there is no such monetary unit!

My point is if you are doing any DIVISION, then you need to understand what you are TRYING to do, what the organization's policies are on this sort of thing... in which case it should be possible to implement what you want with Decimal quantizing.

Now -- if you DO *really* want to do division of Decimals, and you want to carry arbitrary "exactness" around, you *really* don't want to use the `Decimal` object... **You want to use the `Fraction` object.**

With that, your example would work like this:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> a = Fraction(1,3)
>>> a
Fraction(1, 3)
>>> b = Fraction(2,3)
>>> b
Fraction(2, 3)
>>> a == b
False
>>> a == b - a
True
>>> a + b == Fraction(1, 1)
True
>>> 2 * a == b
True
```

OK, well, even a caveat there: `Fraction` objects are the ratio of two integers, so you'd need to multiply by the right power of 10 and carry that around ad-hoc.

Sound like too much work?  Yes... it probably is!

So, head back to the Decimal object; implement quantization/rounding upon Decimal division and Decimal multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point arithmetics is not accurate :

> Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like
>   1.1 and 2.2 do not have exact representations in binary floating point. End users typically would not expect `1.1 + 2.2` to display as
>   `3.3000000000000003` as it does with binary floating point

You have to choose a resolution and truncate everything past it :

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
>>> getcontext().prec = 28
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

You will obviously get some rounding error which will grow with the number of operations so you have to choose your resolution carefully.

Answer (score -1):

There is another approach that may work for you:

- Continue to do all your calculations in floating point values
- When you need to compare for equality, use `round(val, places)`

For example:

```
>>> a = 1./3
>>> a
0.33333333333333331
>>> b = 2./3
>>> b
0.66666666666666663
>>> b-a
0.33333333333333331
>>> round(a,2) == round(b-a, 2)
True
```

If you'd like, create a function `equals_to_the_cent()`:

```
>>> def equals_to_the_cent(a, b):
...   return round(a, 2) == round(b, 2)
...
>>> equals_to_the_cent(a, b)
False
>>> equals_to_the_cent(a, b-a)
True
>>> equals_to_the_cent(1-a, b)
True
```